# IIS Express has been stopped using ASP Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I use asp core for my project.
in debug mode, I can not see my views in browsers, since IIS Express starts and stops suddenly! So, the web page is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "buildOptions": {
    "platform": "anycpu",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
```

check the `platform` in `project.json`.
since we are working in a team on the project the platform was x86 based on other system.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thing happen to me from time to time.  The last time was caused when I moved an application from a development system to a test system.  The problem was not having the correct version of asp.net-core on the test machine.  Other missing DLL's have caused me similar problems.

To find the problem I needed to look at the logs. There will be a message somewhere.  I would start with the IISExpress log (default location %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress).  You might find something in the windows event logs (use event viewer).  Other things I have tried are to invoke the application directly - have a look at this article for the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24412/dotnetexe-instantly-crashes-when-debugging-aspnet.html). (The article also shows how to use WinDbg to grab an error message and gives a few other hints.)